# Java DOM parsing fails to read node

Tags: java, parsing, dom, element, nodes

I am trying to values of specific Nodes from an xml file, this is working fine.

However, there is one line i can't read which is :

```
<misc viewers="898" duration="6684"/>
```

I can find the node, but getNodeValue() and getTextContext() both return null.

Is there a workaround to get the contents of this line?

Thanks

edit : i am using this loop to find nodes

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println("Title: "
                    + getElementValue(element, "title"));
            System.out
                    .println("embed: " + getElementValue(element, "misc"));

            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: The problematic line seems to be missing from your question!
And if possible, please post code which demonstrates the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewers` and `duration` are attributes of the `misc` node, not values.  You need to call `getAttributes()` to get a NamedNodeMap of all the attributes, then call `getNamedItem()` on your node map to access a specific attribute.

Comment: Thanks i wrote the following piece of code to test this, however it resulted in a nullpointer at map.getNamedItem.. Node tmp = element.getElementsByTagName("misc").item(0);
    
    if(tmp.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("misc")) {
     
     NamedNodeMap map = element.getAttributes();
     System.out.println(map.getNamedItem("viewers").getNodeName());
    }

Comment: you're calling `getAttributes()` on the wrong thing, I think.  Shouldn't it be called on `tmp` and not `element`?